# pyspark save max value of a column into a parameter?

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark, if I use the following code to calculate max value, I will get result like "Row(max(age)=5)]". But is there a way that I can save the output value 5 into a parameter such as max_age?

```
print(x.agg({"age": "max"}).collect())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You simply need to extract the value.

```py
max_age = x.agg({"age": "max"}).collect()[0]['max(age)']
```